# Name for this type of programming construct/design/pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Please don't chalk this up as a dumb question.  This may seem very obvious to some, but it is not to me.

I am working on a very, very large codebase.

I continually see, in numerous classes, this pattern:

```
public class myClass {
    public myClass[] doGetMyClassList(final String someParam) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

The class contains a method that returns an array or a list of itself.

Is there a name for this?  I would like to know if this belongs to some kind of programming practice.

Comment: Looks like a [Creational Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern), but not any of the common ones.

Comment: @SoylentGreen What else is around that class. There's a few that could be what it is and several others that it could be a bastardized child of.

Comment: it could be active record if the values are being fetched out of a persistence store, though this would requirehaving some other methods like update or some such.

Comment: Is the "some code" creating the list elements?

Comment: @Taylor I think your asking if the method makes a database call to create the list it returns? Yes, it does.

Comment: @AndyThomas Yes, it does.

Comment: Looks like a sort of factory that is not static, but still creating a number of instances based on pre-conditions in `someParams`. Whatever the pattern it is quite an ugly one: could it belong to a `bad programming practice` or you are confident that that large code base has only good programming practices?

Comment: @wheaties I'm not sure what you mean by what is around it? There are no other methods like this in the class (where the object(s) returned is itself).

Comment: For me it looks like something in between ActiveRecord and Spring Framework's @Service - it might not be a desing pattern in normal sense, more like common practice in some framework/project. I think I saw several times something that was so standardized it looked like a DP but in fact was just a project-specific practice. Did you tried to ask someone else working on that specific codebase?

Comment: @maddening I have not asked anyone else yet (but I definitely can, and will).  You mention spring - we ARE using Spring Data JDBC Connections ultimately for our database access.  The "//somecode" I mention in the post, in fact, does make that database call where the spring mapping takes place.  Just an FYI.

Comment: @SoylentGreen I mean, what other methods are around it? What `private` or `protected` member variables does it have? This is critical to determining what type of "pattern" it is.

Comment: As far as I remember spring has several constructions that are specific to it and using of some of them are considered *good practice*. For instance it has named instance that is used as (and sometimes even called) a singleton even though it's **not** a singleton. I can only guess that someone wrote some mapping that use reflection to find some method basing on class name in something used like a @Service, and so standardized naming makes it possible to find it just by name (why not use annotation though). But it's a long shot and only long time project members could say for sure.

Comment: It may be active record then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern

Comment: @Oleg I am newly assigned to this project.  I am not confident at all about good programming practices.

Comment: @SoylentGreen I'd say that after so many people looked at it and commented on it it is unlikely to be a good programming practice. It definitely does not look like one: arrays for one, having one instance to create a number of same-class instances for another one, and a single `String` as parameters rounding it up.

Comment: Asking what design pattern this uses kind of misses the point; that's just a name. Not all good code uses a widely recognized pattern, and not all code that uses a widely recognized pattern is good. Whether it's good code has more to do with whether it works and how easy it is to understand and change. If it works, is straightforward and obvious, and isn't something that will fall apart if other parts of the system change, then it's probably fine.

Comment: Note that the pattern could easily match, eg, a file interface, where the method returns a list of files matching the provided pattern string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type signature alone doesn't tell you what pattern it is, you also need to know what it collaborates with and how it's used.

It seems like it might be attempting to do [the repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), in which a repository class fetches collections of some other class according to parameters passed in.  However, you would typically make the repository a separate class from the class it is fetching for you.  It's kind of hard to switch out to another repository for testing or other reasons when the class just returns it's own type.

Answer (score 2):

Though I could not find an explicit design pattern or a well defined interface.  I find a parallel here

- [listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) method of [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) which returns an array of File objects if its a directory.

Also any other usecase where objects of same class are related could be a parallel. ex: Person class with friends method which returns an array of Person objects.

Generics as a programming construct is a great tool to express these relations(i.e. methods). Self-bound Generics are feasible and are often seen in many places ex:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Grade < T extends Grade >{
private static final int MAX = 5 ;
private int grade;

public Grade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

public T[] getGradesBelow() {
    Grade[] lower = new Grade[this.grade];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.grade; i++) {
        lower[i] = new Grade(i);
    }

    return (T[]) lower;
}

public String toString(){
    return grade + "";
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Grade grade = new Grade(Grade.MAX);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grade.getGradesBelow()));
}
}
```